# Use of Zend view helper

Tags: php, zend-framework

Does any one knows what the exact use of Zend-Framework view helper.I want to use it in one of our application.Before proceeding i want to know what exactly is Zend View helper.

Answer (score 0):

View Helpers are classes that extend functionality of the View layer of your application:

- Encapsulate reusable view logic - use them to avoid code duplication.
- Allow you to move more complex view logic into a class, making that code testable with Unit Tests. By moving PHP code from templates into a view help you will make view scripts easier to read and understand.